# Displaying contents of a list in a "bar graph"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am trying to learn how to combine lists with for and while loops for an upcoming workshop at Uni. I am stumbling on one thing though:

Basically, I have numerical values stored in a list and I want to display it like this:

```
1  IIIII
2  II
3
4  III 
5  II
```

So that I's represent the number, i.e 3 = III

I tried this code (I had already established count as a list earlier in my code):

```
listIndex = 1
while listIndex < len(count):
    print(listIndex, " ", end='')
    for number in count[listIndex]:
        print("I", end='')
    print()
    listIndex += 1
```

But I get the following error:

```
1   Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/USB/workshop7.py", line 145, in <module>
for number in count[index]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

I don't see what I've done wrong, I looked up the error and I don't see why I cant iterate through that for loop?

The for loop should use the listIndex variable to go to the corresponding index in the list and retrieve the value, displaying it as a series of Is to correspond with the number stored there? Any help in understanding where I've gone wrong would be much appreciated. *This is for assessment* (5%) so if you could help my thinking rather than give me the answer, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1: For mentioning that you would like help in flow and thinking rather than answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count[listIndex]` is an int value, not list. You can use `range()` to make list, or even better you can use "string multiply", i.e. `print('I' * count[listIndex])` and omit `for` loop.

Comment: That might be a little too much help for someone who asked for hints to help his thinking, rather than being straight-out given the answer.

Comment: I don't think I gave too much help :-) With `help("range")` she/he will see info about making list of integers. As a beginner she/he apparently don't know Python string multiplying like `"I" * 5`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I added to the code print(type(count)) and it did reveal that it was indeed a list. I also added a print(count) line and it did have positions in the list for all the values I needed.

Comment: Try `print(type(count[listIndex]))`. In your code `count` is a list (array) of integers, and `count[idx]` is an integer. You can make list of integers from 0 up to idx by using `range(idx)`. This is used in loops where you need index.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a list named "count" that contains counts, and you're fetching one of them with count[listIndex]. What's the result? An int, right?

That means that your for loop is trying to do something like:

```
for number in 3:
    print("I", end='')
```

Is "for number in 3" a valid way to do loops in Python? What would be a better way to write that for loop?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Python lists are 0 indexed, so you should start list_index from 0
2. Knowing the count, you don't need to loop to print 'I'. In Python you can simply do:

   `print 'I'*count[list_index]`